# Can't Click Radio Button in Selenium Using Python

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <input type="radio" name="group2" value="yes">
</div>
```

[Full script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrYLg.jpg)

Here are the code which i've tried to click the radio button:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name= "group2"][value="yes"]').click()
```

AND

```
rdbutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name= "group2"][value="yes"]'))).click()
```

AND

```
rdbutton = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='group2']")
for rdbuttons in rdbutton:
    if rdbuttons.is_selected():
        pass
    else:
        rdbuttons.click()
```

Comment: What `error` are you getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using wrong locator. From the `HTML` you have given i think you are trying to click on radio button that have label **Ya** if this is the case then try with below xpath:

```
"//label[contains(text(),'Ya')]"
```

***OR***

```
"//*[normalize-space()='Ya']"
```

If this does not solve your problem, so please explain and add `HTML` of proper element either by screenshot or in `textual` format